# enabled button if password match

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

here is my script

```
$("#reg_confirm_pass").blur(function(){
var user_pass= $("#reg_pass").val();
var user_pass2=$("#reg_confirm_pass").val();
var enter = $("#enter").val();

        if(user_pass.length == 0){
            alert("please fill password first");
            enter.disabled = true;
        } else if (user_pass == user_pass2 ){
            enter.disabled = false;
        } else {
            enter.disabled = true;
            alert("Your password doesn't same");
        }

    });
```

this my html

```
Password : <input  type="password" name="user[user_pass]" id="reg_pass"  required="required">
Confirm password <input type="password" name="user[user_confirm_pass]" id="reg_confirm_pass" required="required">
<button type="submit" id="enter" disabled="true" value="Register">Register</button>
```

i am really new in Javascript and jQuery, and this is my first using jquery. i need to make a disabled button if the password doesn't match but, after i put the same password the button is still disabled.

Comment: I think the only issue is that it should be `var enter = $("#enter");`

Comment: Note that you should also catch the form submit event as an enter / return will still submit the form.

Comment: You have: `enter = $("#enter").val()`, `.disabled` is a DOM property, but  `enter` is not a DOM element. Even if you did just `$("#enter")` it would be a jQuery object, which you cannot not directly access the DOM property from

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```js
$("#reg_confirm_pass").blur(function() {
  var user_pass = $("#reg_pass").val();
  var user_pass2 = $("#reg_confirm_pass").val();
  //var enter = $("#enter").val();

  if (user_pass.length == 0) {
    alert("please fill password first");
    $("#enter").prop('disabled',true)//use prop()
  } else if (user_pass == user_pass2) {
    $("#enter").prop('disabled',false)//use prop()
  } else {
    $("#enter").prop('disabled',true)//use prop()
    alert("Your password doesn't same");
  }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Password :
<input type="password" name="user[user_pass]" id="reg_pass" required="required">Confirm password
<input type="password" name="user[user_confirm_pass]" id="reg_confirm_pass" required="required">
<button type="submit" id="enter" disabled="true" value="Register">Register</button>
```

Use .prop()

Comment: @jeroen i didnt use the enter `val()` because i dont think it is needed in thi s scenario

Comment: @PatrickEvans if you look closely i didnt use it i didnt just delete it.

Comment: Why would you keep repeating `$("#enter")`, why not just knock off the .val() and use the variable

Comment: you could use $("#reg_confirm_pass").onkeyup (function() { }  instead .blur.  that way user will not require to focusout.

Comment: yeah it works. but when i am trying use that code in my full codeigniter, it cant work and the button still disabled but the alert show the notification if the password doesn't same. that code its not mine, i just learn that of this 1 week. and if i use document.regist.enter.disabled=false; "regist" is name of my form and enter is name of submit button, it works but i got another problem when i use that that why im trying use id than name

Answer (score 0):

You need to set disable attribute like this in jquery **$("#enter").attr('disabled',true);**

```
if(user_pass.length == 0){
        alert("please fill password first");
        $("#enter").attr('disabled',true);
    } else if (user_pass == user_pass2 ){
        $("#enter").attr('disabled',false);
    } else {
        $("#enter").attr('disabled',true);
        alert("Your password doesn't same");
    }
```

Comment: isn't disabled a property rather than an attribute - and accessed through .prop()? eg:$("#enter").prop('disabled',true);

Comment: It is treated as both. The disabled attribute is a boolean attribute.  http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_input_disabled.asp

Answer (score 0):

The .prop( propertyName, value ) allow you set one or more properties for the set of matched elements.

### JS

```
$(function() {
  $("#reg_confirm_pass").blur(function() {
    var user_pass = $("#reg_pass").val();
    var confirm_user_pass = $("#reg_confirm_pass").val();
    var enter = $("#enter");

    if (user_pass.length == 0) {
      alert("please fill password first");
      enter.prop('disabled', true)
    } 
    else if (user_pass == confirm_user_pass) {
      enter.prop('disabled', false)
    } 
    else {
      enter.prop('disabled', true)
      alert("Your password doesn't match");
    }
  });
});
```

### HTML

```
Password: <input type="password" name="user[user_pass]" id="reg_pass"  required="required">
Confirm password: <input type="password" name="user[user_confirm_pass]" id="reg_confirm_pass" required="required">
<button type="submit" id="enter" disabled="true" value="Register">Register</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe the other answers are right on target.  I set up a simple 'jsfiddle' using jquery and its .prop() method to better illustrate [here](https://jsfiddle.net/kyv2n2wv/).

NOTE: I would probably bind to another event to make it fire when changes are made to either input element.

```
$("#reg_confirm_pass").blur(function(){
var user_pass= $("#reg_pass").val();
var user_pass2=$("#reg_confirm_pass").val();
var enter = $("#enter").val();

    if(user_pass.length == 0){
        alert("please fill password first");
        $("#enter").prop('disabled',true);
    } else if (user_pass == user_pass2 ){
        $("#enter").prop('disabled',false);
    } else {
        $("#enter").prop('disabled',true);
        alert("Your password doesn't same");
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually `blur` will not enable the button instantly, `keyup` eventhandler does the best job. Here's the below code.

```
$("#reg_pass").keyup(function () {
    var user_pass = $("#reg_pass").val();
    var user_pass2 = $("#reg_confirm_pass").val();

    if (user_pass == user_pass2) {
      $("#enter").prop('disabled', false)//use prop()
    } else {
      $("#enter").prop('disabled', true)//use prop()
    }
  });

  $("#reg_confirm_pass").keyup(function () {
    var user_pass = $("#reg_pass").val();
    var user_pass2 = $("#reg_confirm_pass").val();

    if (user_pass == user_pass2) {
      $("#enter").prop('disabled', false)//use prop()
    } else {
      $("#enter").prop('disabled', true)//use prop()
    }
  });
```

Here it responds to the changes in either of the text boxes instantly. 
[Check it here](http://jsfiddle.net/6gLQU/66/).

Any better solution than this, please let me know. Thank you.